# Angular MatDialog Displayed in the Bottom of the Page

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working in an angular web site, I want to show a mat dialog when a button is clicked. I did it, but the problem is that the dialog alert was shown in the bottom of the page, not in the middle. The dialog was show in an entry components

```
     openDialog() {
        let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MoreDetailsComponent, {
          height: '400px',
          width: '600px',
        });
      }
    }
```

This is how I open the dialog

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi </h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite Animal</mat-label>
    <input matInput >
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button >No Thanks</button>
  <button mat-button  cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```

and this is how it looks

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBHL2.png)

Comment: Can you try to make a Stackblitz?

Comment: This code should work fine and open the dialog in the middle as you expect it to be. Something else is messing with your styling. Can you try to recreate it in stackblitz?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular MatDialog Diplayed in the Bottom of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66970691/angular-matdialog-diplayed-in-the-bottom-of-the-page)